# Tinymce content with image link

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I am facing a problem in tinymce content. The content is basically a image link but i want to show this just as a link means to show the whole link as a text format. But it comes as a image. As follows

```
<a href='http://www.demo.com'><img src="createnew.gif" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, insert your html code as text into content box. then click your text and click to link button and set your link

Comment: No you didn't got my intension, i want to show the whole link as a text format. I have updated my query.